# How do I get the most recent comments of Facebook?

Tags: facebook, android-activity, widget, comments, facebook-feed

So I have a [comments box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) of Facebook on my site ( one on each article I have on my blog ). My client likes a widget with the most recent comments on his site. I found the Activity Feed with the note:

> Activity is also displayed when users share content from your site in
>   Facebook or if they comment on a page on your site in the Comments
>   box.

I filled in the App ID, but it does not show the comments? Does anyone have an idea how I can get the most recent comments posted in the activity feed?

Comment: Are you able to moderatie your comments? Do you have `fb:app_id` with same Application ID OpenGraph meta in your pages as you used in Activity Feed?

Comment: Yes to both. There is a tool I can use in Facebook to see all the public comments on a certain app_id and that works, but how to implement that on your website.

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using to show the activity feed, as in the fbml. does it show anything, like any activity if not comments?

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve your comments by your URL, not by app ID.

The comments for every URL can be accessed via the graph API. Simply go to: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL}.

For example, the comments on this URL can be accessed via: https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments.

Detailed information: [How do I access the comments left on my site?](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

Some more about comment box: [Adding new features to Comments Box](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/)

Comment: I understand but I like to retrieve the comments throughout the website, without querying every url on it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Once I saw similar question, but there was no solution found.

Comment: That's unfortunate to hear. I see no reason why one would not be able to receive the public reactions belonging to an APP_ID :(